# How can I dynamically change jvector map's marker size according to Some Value?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I am following http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/usa/ map to implement.
It is easy and well documented also.
But there is a map of region selection which uses markers of different size ,here is link 
http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment// Which I want to implement in my case :

```
 $('#vmap_usa').vectorMap({
  map: 'us_aea_en',
  markers:mapMarkers,
  hoverColor: false,
  color: '#c6c6c6',
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.4,
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
            fill: '#01a04e',
            stroke: '#01a04e',
            "fill-opacity": 0.6,
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-opacity": 1,
             r: 7  //*****I want to set this value at time of adding markers**
          },
          hover: {
            stroke: '#01a04e',
            "stroke-width": 2,
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }
        },
```

I am adding markers by using:

```
    var mapObject = $('#vmap_usa').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
    mapObject.addMarkers(mapMarkers,[]);
```

I am new here so PLEASE LEAVE SOME SUGGESTION.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to me .I got a answer of my question.
this code helped me.

```
 series: {
        markers: [{
          attribute: 'fill',
          min: 5,
          max: 200
        },{
          attribute: 'r',
          scale: [5, 15],
          values:mapMarkersValues,
          min: 5,
          max: 15
        }]
      },
```

mapMarkersValues is a array in which i have pushed Some values dynamically a the time of adding markers .

[this is what i needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeCne.png)